# Difference between PCF DEV and PCF Enterprise

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcfdev

What is the Difference between PCF Dev on premise and PCF Enterprise in terms of Features and support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Pivotal

> PCF Dev is ideally suited to developers wanting to explore or evaluate PCF, or those already actively building cloud-native applications to be run on PCF. Working with PCF Dev, developers can experience the power of PCF - from the accelerated development cycles enabled by consistent, structured builds to the operational excellence unlocked through integrated logging, metrics and health monitoring and management.

PCF Dev is a very skinny version of PCF running on a single vm either on VirtualBox or VMWare Fusion; basically meant strictly to run on a laptop or PC. PCF Dev comes with Redis, RabbitMQ, and MySQL OR RMQ, MySql, and SCS tiles.

So, it is a very good solution to spin up and deploy microservices and test; a good solution for a developer for quick turnaround.

---

PCF Dev does not have Bosh.

> `BOSH` is an open source tool for release engineering, deployment, lifecycle management, and monitoring of distributed systems.
>
> Cloud Foundry uses BOSH as the interaction layer with IAAS. BOSH allows  abstraction and standardize interaction to the IAAS. BOSH interacts with IAAS using Cloud Provide Interface (CPI), which is implemented by the IAAS vendor (VMWare, AWS, Google, MS etc).

On PCF Dev you cannot add any other tiles. On a real PCF foundation, depending on business needs you may require a lot more tiles.

A PCF Enterprise, as you called it, is a PCF foundation built for production. It has lot of features. But some of the key features are..

1. Secure by default
2. Self healing and Redundancy (both at app level, and at vm level via bosh resurrector)
3. Scalability
4. Polyglot support

I suggest you read the other features on Pivotal's website.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thank You, Can you please help me out with One more Information. As I gone through the PCF dev. In the Marketplace for Mysql, it is showing the 2 plans for p-MySQL  512mb and 1gb What if I want to extend it to more than the given plans. What could be the solution for this?

Comment: On PCF DEV, those are the plans you get. On PCF Enterprise, you can create your own plans. Last I check, you can have a mysql db up to 1 TB. Lot of things that go in a sizing decision. Rest assured most of your needs will be covered on PCF Enterprise.